# changing superview frame should not effect its subviews frame

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

there

I have a `viewController` ,the hierarchy is something like this

`UIView->imageview->uiview->uiimageView->uitableview.`

Now i want to change height of only first two object of my hierarchy i.e `UIView` and `UIImageView` without effecting frames of other `subviews`.Please help me.

Comment: all this done through xib. arrange all control properly...

Comment: i am not using nib i am drawing all this by code

Comment: I have no knowledge on autoresizing  mask,Plz help me some one

Comment: so you need to set all view frame perfectly..

Comment: at first i am setting my ViewController frame {0.0,500.0,1024,200.0} ,after some button action its height should reset to 0.0

Comment: Go learn about auto layout, come back and ask specific questions if it goes wrong: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your original question, this will work for you.

```
self.view.autoResizeSubviews = NO;
self.myImageView.autoResizeSubviews = NO;
```

and then resize.